# Possible to trick plugin by "faking" a website?

Tags: windows-7, website, browser-plugin

This one seems like a long shot, but I'll try anyways.
I have a web videogame that I downloaded from an old website. Now that website has gone down. I have the game and all the resources the game requires. The problem is, said game is only looking for the required textures, sounds, etc. on the old domain, not locally within my own folders.

So for example:

-There used to be a browser plugin based webgame hosted at http://example.com

-A sound in mp3 format that the game required was stored at http://example.com/sounds/examplesound.mp3

-I downloaded both the game and the sound effect to my hard drive, so I could play it, but the problem is that despite the fact the game is on my hard drive, it is still looking for the sound effect at example.com

-Now example.com is down, and despite the fact I have the sound, I can't use it because the game won't search for it locally.

I was wondering if it was possible to "trick" my computer into thinking there still is something at example.com even though there isn't, similar to the way I can "trick" my computer with the use of Apache into thinking there is a website called localhost (even though there isn't). Is this possible with any program at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add an entry like

```
127.0.0.1     example.com
```

That will cause `example.com` to resolve to your local machine. You can then set up a web server on your local machine that serves the necessary files.

Comment: For web servers there are lots of options but [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) comes ready to run (w/ apache) out of the box and has a system tray icon to easily turn it off or on (it comes with PHP and MySQL too, which are unnecessary for this and could be disabled). Not the greatest option for serving an actual site, but super easy to get up and running (that's its main goal) and more than adequate for this task. You might have to make a small edit to the web configuration file to get it to serve example.com URLs, but no big deal, just set it up as if your domain name was example.com.

Comment: I use XAMPP which I figure is probably the same deal? Anyhow, thanks for this answer. I havn't tried it yet but when I do and if it works I will mark as correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: IMO, the best web server to run for simple lightweight file serving is [Civetweb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/civetweb/), or its now semi-commercial progenitor [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/).